# Hibernate Column Formula returning null

Tags: java, hibernate

In my hibernate mapping file, to obtain the FULL NAME of an employee, I have defined Column Formula as following.

```
<property name="empFirstName" column="emp_First_Name" type="string"
        not-null="false" lazy="false" />
    <property name="empLastName" column="emp_Last_Name" type="string"
        not-null="false" lazy="false" /><property name="fullName" formula="concat(emp_First_Name, ' ', emp_Last_Name)" />
```

But It returns **null** if any one of the property(either FIRST or LAST NAME) is **null**. How can I make it to return empty string for the null property..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `COALESCE()` on the entire column formula:

```
<property name="fullName"
          formula="select coalesce(concat(emp_First_Name, ' ', emp_Last_Name), '') from employee" />
```

The way `COALESCE(A, B)` works in JPA or raw SQL is that it outputs `A` when `A` is not null, and it outputs `B` when `A` is null.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same problem :(

Comment: Thank U @TimBiegeleisen It helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is about how to handle null if each property(firstName or lastName) gets null.

In your code you should do something like this (object creation and set FirstName and lastName)

For example :
     `String firstName = "Joe";
     account.setFirstname(firstName);`

Simply you can check firstName with null value and make it empty like this

```
if(firstName.equal(null))
   firstName = ""; // set an empty value to it.
```

I hope this helps you !

Comment: Yes definitely...This is a way @MohammadRezaKhatami

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

COALESCE(A, B) returns A if A is not null and returns B if A is null

Therefore what I need here is

```
CONCAT( COALESCE(emp_First_Name,''),'',COALESCE(emp_Last_Name,'') )
```

hence if one of the properties is null, the other property is returned and not null. Empty string is returned if both the properties are null